# Git/SVN interop (preserving histories for both repositories)

Tags: git, git-svn

I'm developing a software module for an application, owned by a customer with SVN-based development process. Up to now, I have been used my own Git repository in doing so.

Now, the module is mature enough to become part of the clients SVN tree. I did some git-svn based work in the past, but never with two initially independent repositories (the git part was always a clone taken from SVN).

Is it possible to 'inject' a standalone git repository into a Subversion repository and let also his history become part of the SVN's repo? After that 'normal' work with git-svn on top of SVN should follow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest the following:

1. `git svn clone` the Subversion repository
2. Add your existing git repository as a remote (let's call it `mod`) in the git-svn repo
3. Fetch your module work into the git-svn repo and checkout into a new branch:

   `git fetch mod && git checkout mod/master -b mod-svn`
4. Rebase that branch against the latest from subversion with `git svn rebase`. At this point you should have a linear history with everything from Subversion followed by all your module work.
5. `git svn dcommit` to save your module work into Subversion